# Is there a way to have a grease pencil stroke follow the animation of a different stroke similar to parenting an object to another?

Tags: animation, rigging, workflow, grease-pencil

I'm developing a grease pencil workflow and am hoping there is a way to have a stroke (or layer) follow the animation of another stroke.  Examples:  Draw and animate a body moving and have clothing stroke follow body strokes or Draw and animate simple eyes and have eyelashes follow simple eye strokes.

Similar to how a child object can follow the transformation of a parent object
[image]
[image]

I would like a stroke to follow the animation of another stroke.  Certain strokes can be rigged to armature and follow that motion with weight paint.  So I was trying to create vertex groups and do something with that?

[image]
[image]
[image]

In this example, I want the eyelashes (a stroke on one one layer) to stick to the vertices of the the top of the eye.  I'm trying to avoid drawing as many in between frames as possible.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're after but it doesn't seem likely. Maybe post some screenshots of what you tried so far?

Comment: Just updates post, hopefully is helps?  Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Then I'm affraid you can't without setting up an armature to rig it. Theoretically you could use the hook modifier but for some reason it doesn't show vertex groups in GP objects (bug?). But neither would adjust the change in perspective. If you sculpt the strokes from one to another you could interpolate them?